# How to deal with NancyFX serialized DateTime?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, datetime, nancy

I am sending a `DateTime` instance to the browser using NancyFX. The object that contains the date gets serialized as:

```
{ "foo": "\/Date(1378108800000)\/", "bar": "baz", … }
```

Now my question is how to deal with that serialized date value. Apparently, I can not hand it over to a `Date` constructor call in JavaScript. Of course I could use `substring` and / or a regular expression to strip out the number and hand that over to the `Date` constructor, but I guess that there must be a more intelligent (= standard) way.

Any hints?

PS: I have seen [How to serialize DateTimeOffset as JSON in NancyFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449673/how-to-serialize-datetimeoffset-as-json-in-nancyfx), but that does not answer my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON to receive a Date object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511705/how-to-parse-json-to-receive-a-date-object-in-javascript)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509447/613130

Comment: It's not a duplicate, as I have explicitly asked about a way *without* a regex, and the provided answer uses a regex ;-)

Comment: The point is that the linked response isn't using a regex to modify the JSON, it's using an extension of JSON.parse to parse non-recognized types. There can't be a "more standard way" because that format for Date is specific of .NET "stock" JSON serializer. The other possible response would be "use JSON.NET"

Comment: Yes, but the extension internally uses a regex ;-)

Comment: You could use a substring...

Comment: To quote from my question: *Of course I could use substring and / or a regular expression to strip out the number and hand that over to the Date constructor, but I guess that there must be a more intelligent (= standard) way.*

Comment: @GoloRoden We have to read your question with a 10 foot pole... You didn't even use the [Javascript] tag for a question (I know because I added it) that you seem to want to resolve client-side. Good answers need good questions.

Comment: I didn't mention that I want to resolve it client-side. I just asked whether there is a better solution than regex / substring. Whether it's client- or server-side doesn't matter. But, never mind ;-)

Comment: @GoloRoden You asked `Now my question is how to deal with that serialized date value.`... All your examples where of Javascript... 1+1 == 2. Technically even a response like "use JSON.NET" would be against your request. You can always modify your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be a more intelligent way. You have two possibilities:

- Handle server side: use Json.NET instead of the stock serializer of .NET, perhaps through the Nancy.Fx-Json.NET bindings [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet)
- Handle it client-side, through the reviver parameter of [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) as showed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509447/613130

(and surely there can't be a more standard way, because that formatting is used only by the .NET stock JSON serializers)

I'll say that normally I would choose the first, but then you would have to recheck every generated JSON, so perhaps the second option is easier to implement. You could even replace the `JSON.parse` with a `JSON.parse` that does it.

Comment: I handled it server-side, using your proposed option #1. Thanks for pointing this out :-)